# trigger on delete,on update for table with many columns that reference to one column

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have a table (child) with about 50 columns that about 30 columns reference to one column as Id in another table(parent).
I want when I update Id, then all columns in child table that have parent value also will update and when I deleted row from parent table, in child table set null.
my problem is how get columns from child table that have desire value and update them.
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805941/add-datemodified-column-with-an-update-trigger-to-all-tables-that-contain-a-d)
and [this one](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/)
but I do'nt know how use them into trigger.
Whats the easiest/best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find solution:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteUser]

ON dbo.ParentTable

INSTEAD OF DELETE

AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 declare @Search varchar(200)

 select @Search=d.Id from deleted as d   

Declare @tablevar table(Id  nvarchar(200),ColName  nvarchar(200))

--FindStringAndReturnCols return the name of columns And Id's of rows that have value

insert into @tablevar(Id,ColName) exec FindStringAndReturnCols @Search

declare @Id nvarchar(200), @ColName nvarchar(200),@SqlQuery as nvarchar(max)

Declare c Cursor For Select Id,ColName From @tablevar

Open c

Fetch  c into @Id,@ColName


While @@Fetch_Status=0

 Begin

 set  @SqlQuery=''

 set @SqlQuery= 'update ChildTable set '+ @ColName +' = null where Id like N''%'+@Id+'%'''

   exec (@SqlQuery)

   Fetch  c into @Id,@ColName
End

delete from Parent where Id=@Search

Close c

Deallocate c

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A foreign key (FK) is a column or combination of columns that is used
>   to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables. You
>   can create a foreign key by defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint when you
>   create or modify a table.
>
> In a foreign key reference, a link is created between two tables when
>   the column or columns that hold the primary key value for one table
>   are referenced by the column or columns in another table. This column
>   becomes a foreign key in the second table.

Also have a look at [Creating and Modifying FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Also look at [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> By using cascading referential integrity constraints, you can define
>   the actions that the SQL Server takes when a user tries to delete or
>   update a key to which existing foreign keys point.

Comment: I use FOREIGN KEY for reference.I try use on update and on delete on all columns that REFERENCES to Id but I get this error:Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK74988DB24B3C886' on table 'child' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.,so I Knew must be used trigger for this Purpose.

Comment: how I do this astander?